# How to use table-row and float element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was trying to make one div equal to the height of another div. This is solved, but when I should have float left for the elements to get margin, it doesn't work. How can this fix so I can use float left and table-row?

JSFIDDLE (this is working, but without margin. I have removed the `float: left` of the grid>
http://jsfiddle.net/XLES6/67/

JSFIDDLE (this the not working one, with the `float: left` of the grid_x)
http://jsfiddle.net/XLES6/68/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/XLES6/69/ inline block?

Comment: No, then the image will not align at the bottom of the div. @JFit